# Как организовать регулярное получение информации со стороннего сайта

Tags: javascript, php

Появился такой вопрос. Для сайта нужна функция, которая следит за стеной сообщества ВК и добавляет новые записи в БД, откуда они уже переносятся на сайт.
И вот возник вопрос, эта функция была прописана на php и вызывается раз в минуту. То есть она будет вызываться раз в минуту у всех кто зашел на сайт? Значит ее надо писать в другом месте?

```
<?php
    $method = 'wall.get';
    $token = '';
    $version = 5.78;
    $owner_id = ''; 

    $params = http_build_query([
        'owner_id' => $owner_id,
        'filter' => 'all',
        'count' => '5',
        'access_token' => $token,
        'v' => $version
        //...
    ]);

    $url = "https://api.vk.com/method/{$method}?{$params}&access_token={$token}&v={$version}";

    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

    echo ($result['response']['items'][0]['date']);

    $fp = fopen('../data/vk.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
//+добавление записей в бд
```

?>

Comment: Вызывается раз в минуту кем где?

Comment: Сама себя вызывает раз в минуту чтобы посмотреть не появились ли новые записи на стене

Comment: Чтобы она начала вызывать сама себя, её должен запустить первый раз кто-то другой. Кто, где и когда это сделал?

Comment: Когда перешел на страницу /feed. Она получила записи со стены, положила их в бд и из бд вывела на сайт. И скрипт получения записей и запись в бд должен постоянно работать на сервере.А при обращении к только скрипт вывода из бд

Comment: В таком случае мне не совсем понятен механизм вызова самой себя. Лучше просто покажите её код

Comment: Ну, в показанном вами коде никакого «вызова самой себя» не наблюдается. А этот скрипт в таком виде можно совершенно спокойно запихнуть в упомянутый в ответе cron (не забыв настроить корректные пути к файлам и права доступа), и тогда он не будет связан с сайтом и его посетителями совершенно никак (только с бд разве что)

Comment: Я так понял можно использовать CRON, так и прописать свое консольное приложение которое так же будет запущено на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если эта функция привязана к событию, например: переход на определённую страницу или нажатие на кнопку, то тогда да, она будет выполнятся по этому действию, для всех пользователей которые его выполнят. Если я вас полностью понял вам нужно смотреть в сторону CRON

Comment: Нет, ни к какому событию не привязана и ни от чего не зависит. Сам пользователь вызвать ее не может. CRON что то похоже на правду

Comment: @АнульевПавел но из ваших комментариев получается, что она привязана к событию посещения страницы /feed. По-моему вы всё-таки что-то не договариваете

Comment: К странице привязан вывод из БД. А отслеживать появление новых записей она должна постоянно

Comment: @АнульевПавел В вашем случае, только CRON, сам скрипт может находится где угодно, вызывайте его в кроне и всё будет так, как вы хотите.